# Sign up and signin with google and firebase not redirecting to destined page

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

Am working on a project that I was suppose to finished by next week latest, but am facing issue of not redirecting to destined page in flutter google and firebase sign up/sign in.

## Here's my dependencies version:

```
google_sign_in: ^4.0.14
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.11
fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
```

## Here's my login code logic.

```
   import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
   import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
   import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
  import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'home.dart';
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}
class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  bool loading = false;
  bool isLogedin = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    issignedIn();
  }
  void issignedIn() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLogedin = await googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
    if (isLogedin) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
    }
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  }
  Future handleSignIn() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken);
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser =
        (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential));

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .where("id", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
          .getDocuments();
      final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
      if (documents.length == 0) {
        //Insert the user to our collection
        Firestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .document(firebaseUser.uid)
            .setData({
          "id": firebaseUser.uid,
          "username": firebaseUser.displayName,
          "email": firebaseUser.email,
          "profilePicture": firebaseUser.photoUrl
        });
        await preferences.setString("id", firebaseUser.uid);
        await preferences.setString("username", firebaseUser.displayName);
        await preferences.setString("email", firebaseUser.email);
        await preferences.setString("photoUrl", firebaseUser.displayName);
      } else {
        await preferences.setString("id", documents[0]['id']);
        await preferences.setString("username", documents[0]['username']);
        await preferences.setString("email", documents[0]['email']);
        await preferences.setString("photoUrl", documents[0]['photoUrl']);
      }
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Logged in successfully");
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    } else {}
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Login",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                handleSignIn();
              },
              child: Text(
                "Sign in/ Sign up with google",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: loading ?? true,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps loading like forever. May be am not doing something right. A help with the code is highly appreciated.
Please, help out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47oRM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just check quickly that the build.gradle file edits were made in the correct file as there are two of them and i've seen that mistake often. Also there is a problem with some android x devices as covered [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30776#issuecomment-481174659) that could cause this.

1) check the indentation of imports at the head of the page and make sure you have included `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`.

2) ~line 50 ish: `FirebaseUser firebaseUser =(await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential));`

you may want to try replacing with: `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;`

3) ... will run a test later if i have time ( ﾟヮﾟ) 
`Later =>` with the change above, this code does work for me. I loaded it into one of my firebase projects and it logs me in. It does not redirect to home as you have not called `issignedIn()` in the button flow. You could add it in after  `Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Logged in successfully");` replacing `setState((){...});` but i would recommend changing this function to a  [`onAuthStateChange`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) method if you are comfortable using listeners. If you still cant get it working, post the content of you build.gradle files and the pubspec.yaml and any errors from the debug console.

and just as a note: adding `try, catch` logic or `then.error` with asynchronous functions is recommended, especially when using networks [here](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling). I see people ignore it for prototyping but it can really help with [Firebase custom error states](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/725#issue-506365801)

Comment: Thanks @Jack, I'll do as you have said and give you reply

Answer (score 0):

I made this video showing how to get firebase auth setup with flutter. It's a bit of a different code structure than what you posted but I think more flexible if you were interested in refactoring. https://youtu.be/iTYD13w6Duo